Read PCX file byte by byte and apply it to a texture in Unity C#
I'm trying to as a challenge to myself read a  pcx file byte by byte and convert it to a texture in Unity. I am reading the data just fine, however actually applying it to be a proper texture never comes out right, just a mess of pixels that don't even fill out the whole object. What am I missing here? Here is my code as it is.
public class Parser : MonoBehaviour

{
public MeshRenderer mat;
public int bitsInPlane;
public int minX;
public int minY;
public int maxX;
public int maxY;
public int horzDPI;
public int vertDPI;
public int numColorPlanes;
public int bytesPerColorPlane;
public int horzSourceScreen;
public int vertSourceScreen;
public int startingPoint;

void Start()
{
    Application.targetFrameRate = 24;
    List<byte> byteStream = new List<byte>();
    byteStream = readImageData();
    printBytes(byteStream);
    readBytesHeader(byteStream);
    drawTexture(byteStream);
}

void Update()
{
    
}

List<byte> readImageData()
{
    string pcxPath = Application.dataPath + "/resources/bagit_icon.pcx";
    List<byte> readByteStream = new List<byte>();
    using (var stream = File.Open(pcxPath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var bReader = new BinaryReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, false))
        {
            while (stream.Position != stream.Length)
            {
                readByteStream.Add(bReader.ReadByte());

            }
        }
    }

    return readByteStream;
}

void printBytes(List<byte> bytes)
{
    int offset = 0;
    foreach (var b in bytes)
    {
        Debug.Log(offset.ToString("X4") + " [" + offset + "]: " + b);
        offset++;
    }
}

void readBytesHeader(List<byte> bytes)
{
    bitsInPlane = bytes[3];
    minX = bytes[4]; minY = bytes[6];
    maxX = bytes[8]; maxY = bytes[10];
    horzDPI = bytes[12];
    vertDPI = bytes[14];
    numColorPlanes = bytes[65];
    bytesPerColorPlane = bytes[66];
    horzSourceScreen = bytes[70];
    vertSourceScreen = bytes[72];
    startingPoint = 128;
}

void drawTexture(List<byte> bytes) 
{
    int currentPoint = startingPoint;
    Debug.Log("BYTES: " + bytes);
    Debug.Log("Size Calculation: " + ((bytes.Count - startingPoint) / 3) + " " + ((maxX / horzDPI) * (maxY / vertDPI)));
    Texture2D imgTexture = new Texture2D(maxX + 1, maxY + 1, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);


    for (int y = 0; y < maxY; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < maxX; x++)
        {
            if(currentPoint <= bytes.Count - 3)
            {
               Debug.Log("COLOR: " + bytes[currentPoint] + " " + bytes[currentPoint + 1] + " " + bytes[currentPoint + 2]);
                Color newColor = new Color(bytes[currentPoint], bytes[currentPoint + 1], bytes[currentPoint + 2]);
                
                imgTexture.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
                currentPoint += 3;
            }

        }
    }
    imgTexture.Apply();
    mat.materials[0].mainTexture = imgTexture;
}

}
This is what it comes out as

And here is a link to the specific pcx file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y432te3nwZx5WFVEDYrxnaIjZS5WYZ6f/view?usp=drive_link
Thank you

Not familiar with PCX format but one thing that stands out is minX = bytes[4]; minY = bytes[6]; maxX = bytes[8]; maxY = bytes[10]; What is happening to bytes 5 7 9 and 11, they just get ignored. Are you supposed to be reading 2 bytes (16bit int) instead?

After checking the format it seems you are trying to decode it as "no encoding, 24bit color", when the file is actually "run-length encoding, 256-color palette".

If what I need to change is the textureformat, what of these options would I need to use? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.html ? One of the 8 bit formats is what I would assume. Also there isn't an alpha channel.
